# Drawing a smooth implicit surface with misc3d

Tags: r, rgl

The `misc3d` package provides a great implementation of the marching cubes algorithm, allowing to plot implicit surfaces.

For example, let's plot a Dupin cyclide:

```
a = 0.94; mu = 0.56; c = 0.34 # cyclide parameters
f <- function(x, y, z, a, c, mu){ # implicit equation f(x,y,z)=0
  b <- sqrt(a^2-c^2)
  (x^2+y^2+z^2-mu^2+b^2)^2 - 4*(a*x-c*mu)^2 - 4*b^2*y^2
}
# define the "voxel"
nx <- 50; ny <- 50; nz <- 25
x <- seq(-c-mu-a, abs(mu-c)+a, length=nx) 
y <- seq(-mu-a, mu+a, length=ny)
z <- seq(-mu-c, mu+c, length=nz) 
g <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y, z=z)
voxel <- array(with(g, f(x,y,z,a,c,mu)), c(nx,ny,nz))
# plot the surface
library(misc3d)
surf <- computeContour3d(voxel, level=0, x=x, y=y, z=z)
drawScene.rgl(makeTriangles(surf))
```

[image]

Nice, except that the surface is not smooth. 
The documentation of `drawScene.rgl` says: *"Object-specific rendering features such as smoothing and material are controlled by setting in the objects."* I don't know what does that mean. How to get a smooth surface?

I have a solution but not a straightforward one: this solution consists in building a `mesh3d` object from the output of `computeContour3d`, and to include the surface normals in this `mesh3d`.

The surface normals of an implicit surface defined by `f(x,y,z)=0` are simply given by the gradient of `f`. It is not hard to derive the gradient for this example.

```
gradient <- function(xyz,a,c,mu){
  x <- xyz[1]; y <- xyz[2]; z <- xyz[3]
  b <- sqrt(a^2-c^2)
  c(
    2*(2*x)*(x^2+y^2+z^2-mu^2+b^2) - 8*a*(a*x-c*mu),
    2*(2*y)*(x^2+y^2+z^2-mu^2+b^2) - 8*b^2*y,
    2*(2*z)*(x^2+y^2+z^2-mu^2+b^2)
  )
}
```

Then the normals are computed as follows:

```
normals <- apply(surf, 1, function(xyz){
  gradient(xyz,a,c,mu)
})
```

Now we are ready to make the `mesh3d` object:

```
mesh <- list(vb = rbind(t(surf),1),
             it = matrix(1:nrow(surf), nrow=3),
             primitivetype = "triangle", 
             normals = rbind(-normals,1))
class(mesh) <- c("mesh3d", "shape3d")
```

And finally to plot it with `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)
shade3d(mesh, color="red")
```

[image]

Nice, the surface is smooth now.

But is there a more straightforward way to get a smooth surface, without building a `mesh3d` object? What do they mean in the documentation: *"Object-specific rendering features such as smoothing and material are controlled by setting in the objects."*?

Comment: Try adding `smooth=1000` to your `makeTriangles` statement, i.e. `drawScene.rgl(makeTriangles(surf, smooth=1000))`

Comment: @G5W Oops sorry, I've just posted an answer with the option `smooth`, before seeing your comment...I will try `smooth=1000`.

Comment: @G5W I've tried. It seems that `smooth=TRUE` is the same as `smooth=1000` when we use the `rgl` rendering.

Comment: I tried another automatic approach:  I used the suggestion from  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/145034 to approximate the normals at grid points by differencing and then interpolated for the triangle vertices (which always lie on a grid line).  This seems to do a bit better than the `addNormals` approach based on the triangle normals, but still shows big artefacts.  So I think if you want a nice smooth surface, you'll have to compute the true normals the way you did.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the documentation is suggesting.  However, you can do it via a mesh object slightly more easily than you did (though the results aren't quite as nice), using the `addNormals()` function to calculate the normals automatically rather than by formula.

Here are the steps:

Compute the surface as you did.

Create the mesh without normals.  This is basically what you did, but using `tmesh3d()`:

```
mesh <- tmesh3d(t(surf), matrix(1:nrow(surf), nrow=3), homogeneous = FALSE)
```

Calculate which vertices are duplicates of which others:

```
verts <- apply(mesh$vb, 2, function(column) paste(column, collapse = " "))
firstcopy <- match(verts, verts)
```

Rewrite the indices to use the first copy.  This is necessary, since the `misc3d` functions give a collection of disconnected triangles; we need to work out which are connected.

```
it <- as.numeric(mesh$it)
it <- firstcopy[it]
dim(it) <- dim(mesh$it)
mesh$it <- it
```

At this point, there are a lot of unused vertices in the mesh; if memory was a problem you might want to add a step to remove them.  I'm going to skip that.

Add the normals

```
mesh <- addNormals(mesh)
```

Here are the before and after shots.  Left is without normals, right is with them.

[image: screenshots]

It's not quite as smooth as your solution using computed normals, but it's not always easy to find those.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option `smooth` in the `makeTriangles` function:

```
drawScene.rgl(makeTriangles(surf, smooth=TRUE))
```

I think the result is equivalent to @user2554330's solution, but this is more straightforward.

[image]

---

## EDIT

The result is highly better with the **rmarchingcubes** package:

```r
library(rmarchingcubes)
contour_shape <- contour3d(
  griddata = voxel, level = 0,
  x = x, y = y, z = z
)
library(rgl)
tmesh <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(contour_shape[["vertices"]]),
  indices = t(contour_shape[["triangles"]]),
  normals = contour_shape[["normals"]],
  homogeneous = FALSE
)
open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 562, 562))
view3d(zoom=0.8)
shade3d(tmesh, color = "darkred")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, definitely preferable.